# SharePoint using SQL Report Server Manager outside of SharePoint farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, reportserver

Can we have SharePoint use SQL Report Server which is already set up outside of SharePoint Farm?

The SQL Server which would be having this SQL Report Server Manager will not have Configuration Database and Content Database but will be a dedicated SQL Report Server Manager use only for SQL reporting services (Native Mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As a short answer:** Yes, you can use a (Native Mode) reporting server outside the SharePoint farm.  It's preferred to use dedicated reporting server from Performance Perspective.

**The only concern** is that the SharePoint server and reporting server should be on the same network or the report server (`Report Service URL / Report Manager URL`) is reachable from the SharePoint server.

---

**To configure SSRS - Native Mode**

- [SQL Server 2016: Install and Configure SSRS](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/50902.sql-server-2016-install-and-configure-ssrs.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2012: Install and Configure SSRS](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/02/04/install-and-configure-ssrs/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Qassas. Any documentation/article will really help me to get this configuration done. Please share if you already have any references.

Comment: Sure For SSRS 2016 : [SQL Server 2016: Install and Configure SSRS] (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/50902.sql-server-2016-install-and-configure-ssrs.aspx) For SSRS 2012 : [SQL Server 2012: Install and Configure SSR](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/02/04/install-and-configure-ssrs/)